# Access all the provide parameters and print them in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a custom command that I create call PUSH

I want to run

`PUSH #1 #2 #3 #4`

I want to dynamically access all my arguments, I seem to have a hard time. How do I correctly do it?

I want to access

`#1 #2 #3 #4`

I know I can not use $1, $2, $3, or $4.

I've tried

`PUSH a b c | echo $@`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat args.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo ${@}

for a in "${@}"; do
    echo ${a}
done

$ bash args.sh foo bar baz
foo bar baz
foo
bar
baz
```

You're on the right track with `$@`.  You can either access all the arguments at once (my first `echo`) or you can use a loop (my `for`) since I assume you'll eventually want to do something besides `echo` in the real script.

Comment: Always double-quote `"$@"`.

Comment: To follow on to what rici said above -- when you say `for a in ${@}`, you get `./yourscript "argument one" "argument two"` printing `argument`, `one`, `argument`, `two` instead of `argument one` and `argument two`. The quotes really are critical.

Comment: Good catches, thanks. I do enough shell that I remember this *after* I get bit, but not enough that I think of it before.  Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing the right thing, but the way that you're testing that
syntax isn't right.  `$@` will give you access to the arguments passed into your
script, but your command, `PUSH #1 #2 #3 #4 | echo $2` has two problems.  First
of all, the first octothorpe is starting a line comment.  you are running `PUSH`
followed by the bash comment, `#1 #2...`. Second, in the scope of this command,
`$@` will reference the argument passed into this shell session, not the
argument passed into the command before it.  To test this syntax correctly, you
need to use it in the script itself, like this:

```
- ❯❯❯ cat push.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $@
- ❯❯❯ ./push.sh one two three
one two three
```

Or even more succinctly,

```
- ❯❯❯ bash -c 'echo $@' here are some args
are some args
```

Comment: Always double-quote `"$@"`.